# How to multiply both sides of $\frac{5}{X_1-X_2} > 10$ by $X_1-X_2$ when $X_i$ are independently drawn random variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, inequality

Suppose we have random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ that are independently and identically distributed.

Suppose I am interested in the inequality $\frac{5}{X_1-X_2} > 10$.

How can I multiply both sides of this inequality by $X_1-X_2$

> Specifically, since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables, I do not know if $X_1 -X_2$ is positive or negative. Therefore, I don't know if I need to reverse the sign of the inequality or not.

An example of where I get confused. Consider the statement $$\frac{5}{X_1-X_2} > 10$$ IF AND ONLY IF $$.5 > X_1-X_2$$. **This would not be a correct statement would it?** In particular, the "IF" direction would fail, i think.

My logic is as follows:

First consider the "ONLY IF" direction. This direction holds because

if $\frac{5}{X_1-X_2} > 10$  then $X_1-X_2$ must be positive, because a negative number cannot be greater than $10$, and we get the result by rearranging.

Now for the "IF" direction, which does not hold.

Suppose  $.5>X_1-X_2$. If $X_1>X_2$ then we can rearrange to get $\frac{5}{X_1-X_2} > 10$ by $X_1-X_2$ . **However**, we cannot be sure that $X_1>X_2$ and if $X_1<X_2$ then we have that $\frac{.5}{X_1-X_2}<10$ when we rearrange `so the "IF" direction does not hold`

Comment: $0.5 > 0 - \frac{1}{4}$, but $\frac{5}{0-\frac{1}{4}} \not > 10$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah i made a mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. I will edit the question

Comment: Isn't this basically a question about real numbers.? Independence does not play a role in re-writing the inequality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My question is basically this: Consider the example I give in the question: Whether the "IF" direction holds depends on if $X_1>X_2$ or not. But since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables we don't know if $X_1>X_2$. So Does the "IF" direction hold or not?

Answer (score 1):

I think $0.5>X_1−X_2$ will fail, like you say. Yes, it must be positive. If you consider $d=X_1-X_2$, then you can graph $\frac5d$ and $10$. The inequality will only be true when $0<d<0.5$ (which incorporates your "must be positive"), so you were almost right:

$$0<X_1-X_2<0.5$$